# Why do the division (/) operators behave differently in VB.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

If you create new projects in C# and VB.NET, then go directly in the Immediate Window and type this:

```
? 567 / 1000
```

C# will return 0, while VB.NET will return 0.567.

To get the same result in C#, you need to type

```
? 567 / 1000.0
```

Why is there this difference? Why does C# require the explicit decimal point after 1000?

Comment: Amazing!
You type "/" in MSDN index, select "/ operator [C#]" and read from the 3rd sentence:
When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. For example, the result of 5 / 2 is 2. To determine the remainder of 5 / 2, use the modulo operator (%). To obtain a quotient as a rational number or fraction, give the dividend or divisor type float or type double. You can do this implicitly by putting a decimal point after the number, as shown in the following example.

I can't believe there's somebody who votes for such a question, answeres on it and votes for answers on it.

Comment: DTashkinov: Apparently, you should read the FAQ of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Dtashkinov I agree 100%.  Basic searching and learning is no longer expected.  Post anything you like and vote.  Missing a semi-colon?  No problem just post it on stackoverflow we can help you.  It is ridiculious!

Comment: Good question, I originally was very strong with C# but due to my current job only use VB.NET, glad you mentioned this as otherwise I'd go back to C# and wonder why division wasn't working the same!

Comment: How is it a good question?  Its idiotic.  If you see something that doesn't look right read the help files.  DTashkinov posted the exact help from C# and to me it is very easy to understand.  Wow integer division returns integer result..so gotta cast or handle appropriately.  Why does it work in vb.net?  Wow look at that the help file states that it performs the division like one would expect without having to cast.

Comment: @JonH and @DTashkinov, while the question may be a "newbie" question, it does benefit people who are searching on google and people who read this site daily. Now the next time someone on Google "division operator different c# vb.net" this page is the third one down. (1st is codeproject, 2nd is MSDN), and seeing as this site is easier to understand for newbies compared to MSDN, would probably be more helpful.

Comment: From FAQ:

What kind of questions can I ask here?
...
of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere
...
No question is too trivial or too "newbie"

Comment: Hmm, maybe I was too pationate, sorry. But discussing what is clearly written in documentation looks strange to me.

Comment: @JonH, There is no bad question, only bad answer/comment. Trust me on that.

Comment: @Jason Nope. I love and appreciate this particular feature.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [/ operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) for **integer operands** does the "integer division" operation (equivalent to [\ operator in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh(VS.80).aspx)). For VB.NET, it's the "normal" division (will give fractional result). In C#, in order to do that, you'll have to cast at least one operand to a floating point type (e.g. `double`) explicitly.

Comment: My guess is that the reason this is different in VB (from C#), is because VB.Net was originally spec'd to retain as much syntactical similarilty to VB6 as possible, so as not alienate the large VB6 user base that existed at the time.  And that's the way it worked in VB6.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, both languages have a long heritage: The way C# works is the way C works and I'm sure / and \ operators behaved this way at least since QBasic days (I *guess* this was the case since earlier BASICs but that's the first thing I've worked with).

Comment: Just in case the poster needed to know how to do it, in C#:
 567.0 / 1000.0;
or 
 (double)567 / 1000;
or even 
 567 / (double)1000;

will give you what you need.

As long as one of the numbers is a double it will perform floating point division.

Comment: I struggled and used CType for both operands of \ in VB.Net until I found this article.

Answer (score 11):

Because in VB.NET, the `/` operator is defined to return a floating-point result. It widens its inputs to `double` and performs the division. In C#, the `/` operator performs integer division when both inputs are integers.

See MSDN for [VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx).

> Divides two numbers and returns a floating-point result.
>
> Before division is performed, any integral numeric expressions are widened to Double.

See MSDN for [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx).

> The division operator (/) divides its first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined division operators.
>
> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer.

To get the same semantics in VB.NET as the `/` operator on integers in C#, use the [`\` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e16fywh.aspx).

> Divides two numbers and returns an integer result.

Answer (score 3):

By default C# is treating 576 / 1000 as integer division so you get an integer as the result.

In VB.NET it's treating it as floating point division.

By adding ".0" on a number in C# you are explicitly telling it this number is a floating point number and hence the division becomes floating point as well.

Answer (score 2):

The languages are different.  In C# the compiler interprets those numbers as integers and uses integer division.  In VB.NET the compiler uses floating point division.

Answer (score 2):

[C# Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[VB.Net Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711630%28VS.71%29.aspx)

VB.Net has both a / and a \ operator. / happens to be the floating point division operator.

Answer (score 0):

C#'s / equalant in VB.Net is \

**C#.Net:**

/ Operator
Divides two numbers and returns an integer result.

**VB.Net:**

/ Operator
Divides two numbers and returns a floating-point result.

\ Operator
Divides two numbers and returns an integer result.