# \ operator in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

I want to know what is purpose of '\' in vb ? I have this statement:

```
frontDigitsToKeep \ 2
```

and I want to convert it to C#.

Please suggest.

Comment: See this recent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013626/vb-net-vs-c-integer-division

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\` is the integer division operator in VB.NET.

For C#, just use the standard `/` operator instead and assign the result to some integer type:

```
frontDigitsToKeep / 2
```

You need an integer typecast if `frontDigitsToKeep` itself isn't an integer:

```
(int) frontDigitsToKeep / 2
```

Comment: and if it isn't, cast it to an integer/long using `(int)`, `(uint)`, `(long)`, or `(ulong)` depending on the expected value range.

Comment: Actually, to get exactly the same behaviour, make sure that both *operands* are of type int (rather than casting the result).

Comment: Does the vb.net operator always round down?

Comment: @Jodrell, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013626/vb-net-vs-c-integer-division, yes

Answer (score 0):

`100 \ 9  = 11` in VB.NET is equivalent to `100 - (100 % 9) / 9` in C#.

```
frontDigitsToKeep - (frontDigitsToKeep % 2) / 2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code in c# is

```
frontDigitsToKeep / 2
```

for such conversion from C# to VB.Net and vb.net to c# follow the link

http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

Say you're trying to compute how many coins are packaged without caring for the leftovers. You would use \ to do integer division.
So `( 4 * 5 ) \ 6` would equal 3.

As for how to put it into C#, you would use `frontDigitsToKeep - (frontDigitsToKeep % 2) / 2`.