# Difference between syntaxes

Tags: c#, gridview, type-conversion

I am working on developing custom pager control to my grid view.

I am using the following syntax to get no of pages:

```
dblpagecount = (doble)(totrecords / grdPages.PageSize);
pagecount = (int)Math.Ceiling(dblPagecount);
```

Using above syntax , if the no of records is 41 and page size is 5 then I am getting pagecount as 8 which should be 9.

If I use the below syntax,

```
double dblPagecount = (double)((decimal)totrecords /grdPages.PageSize);
pagecount = (int)Math.Ceiling(dblPagecount);
```

I am getting exact page count i.e 9

I got the desired result , but unable to understand why the above synatax is not giving desired results.

When I debugged in first case, I observed that dblpagecount is getting result as 8.0 insted of 8.2

Can any one please clarify , how the above statements works ?

Comment: Are totrecords and grdPages.PageSize both int?

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float

Comment: Perhaps you are a former    VB.NET developer. VB.NET behaves differently on integer division http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013626/vb-net-vs-c-sharp-integer-division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer

`int / int = int`

If you want to get a decimal-type number (math-speak here, aka any number with a decimal in it from 3.0 to 3.14159) you have to do something like...

`double / int = double`

`int / double = double`

So just cast one value, and you are good, and that is why the following works...

`double dblPagecount = (double)((decimal)totrecords /grdPages.PageSize);`

Please note that the outer cast is NOT needed, and the inner cast should be of type double! Please read my comment below to get the **general idea** of what you are doing here.

Comment: by the way, the outer `double` cast I think is unnecessary. `DecimalTotRecords / IntGrdPages_PageSize` results in a `double` expression. You then cast that double to a double, and then assign to `dblPagecount`

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski: No it doesn't - dividing a `decimal` by an `int` gives a `decimal`, not a `double`. This is really *not* a good approach. It's overly complicated, and mixes different floating point types completely pointlessly.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, sorry, I was a little more sleepy than I thought. The *general* idea is right, and I updated my answer. The OP understood generally what I was saying it seems, and I wanted to provide an insight into how to evaluate the expressions.

Comment: I still disagree with "and you are good" though - I would still prefer to see the "no floating point required" approach, personally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that both `totrecords` and `grdPages.PageSize` are of type `int`. Therefore, *regardless* of the type of `dblpagecount`, you'll end up with the division being performed in integer arithmetic, which truncates towards 0. However, I wouldn't actually use your second piece of code (and certainly wouldn't use both `double` *and* `decimal` - mixing those is almost always a bad idea). Instead, I'd just use:

```
// Names changes slightly for readability
int pageCount = (totalRecords + grdPages.PageSize - 1) / grdPages.PageSize;
```

This will effectively "round up" without ever requiring any floating point operations.

Comment: @Jon Skeet performing integer division results in no floating-point operations whatsoever? I guess I assumed that floating-point operations occur regardless (it is division), but the result is effectively truncated.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski: It would be an integer machine code operation. I would really hope that wouldn't need to go via floating point code...