# Converting int to float and displaying result not working?

Tags: c#, methods

So I have a method in a class called Rational that passes in two ints, and I want to return a float, however this method is returning 0, and I have no idea why!

```
public static float DisplayFloat(int numer, int denom)
        {
            float result = numer / denom;
            return result;

        }
```

it is getting called like this in my main:

```
Console.WriteLine(Rational.DisplayFloat(12, 36));
```

Any ideas? I have no errors showing up in Visual Studio so I'm dumbfounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`numer` and `denom` are both ints, so when you divide one by the other the result is an int ; the result is then converted to a float, but it's too late because you already lost the fractional part. If you want a float result, cast one of the operands before doing the division:

```
float result = (float)numer / denom;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to cast one of the ints to float

```
public static float DisplayFloat(int numer, int denom)
{
    float result = (float)numer / denom;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(Rational.DisplayFloat(12, 36, Console.ReadLine()));

 public static void DisplayFloat(int numer, int denom, string spaces)
        {
            float result = (float)numer / (float)denom;
            Console.WriteLine("{0:0."+ spaces +"}", result);
        }

what is wrong with this? this is what I was trying to do in the first place (Thank you for your help!!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the numerator or denominator to a float; otherwise, the division is done using integer math only. For example:

```
float result = float(numer) / float(denom);
```

[MSDN has more information.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx). Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953164/why-do-the-division-operators-behave-differently-in-vb-net-and-c/1953173#1953173) to the question [Why do the division (/) operators behave differently in VB.NET and C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1953164/7432)